# How can all different graphs be made following these rules?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Imagine a number $n$ of vertices. How many different graphs can be constructed given the following rules:

1. No segment of the graph can be disconnected, this means there must be a path between any pair of vertices.
2. All connections must be directed with an arrow.
3. A vertex with no inputs has a value of 1.
4. If two vertex are connected, the consequent one must have a bigger
   value than the first one. (This also means there cannot be any
   cycles)
5. If there is a path moving only forward between two vertices, there
   cannot be a direct shortcut connection between them.

Is there an algorithm I can use to make sure I have count them all?

Comment: In the second rule, connection by an arrow means by a directed edge? and can you clarify the first rule?

Comment: Yes, all edges are directed from lower valued vertices to higher.